# Array data in 3 different column

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have an array:

```js
[
  {name: 'task1', status: 'new'},
  {name: 'task2', status: 'progress'},
  {name: 'task3', status: 'completed'},
  {name: 'task4', status: 'progress'},
  {name: 'task5', status: 'new'}
]
```

I need to show the list of the array in 3 columns.

| New task | progressTask | completed task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| task1 | task2 | task3 |
| task5 | task5 |  |

what will be the best process for this.

I can create 3 different array and then iterate it. is there any better way than this.

Comment: I'd probably define how the row is constructed in detail, then create the rows basically and loop over them. You could filter the data by status and then take the n-th item of the array for each row.

Comment: Do you want to create a table in react js?

Comment: @asif yes, I am working on react

Comment: @RiniJaiswal The only odd thing is that you don't really have tabular data here since the number of new tasks does not relate to the completed tasks nor the ones in progress so you might be better of using a div for each status and just put the content in there and let it grow on the y-axis downwards. Otherwise you have to account for the "empty cells" in your table.

Comment: @Muller issue is I am not able to put the data, in specific column.. 

how can I move  {name: 'task1', status: 'new'}, in "New Task" column. ?

Comment: @RiniJaiswal As I said earlier. You filter by the status so you get 3 arrays (newTasks, progressTasks, completedTasks). Then you have to find out the length (let's call it len) of the biggest of the 3 arrays. Then you loop with n=0 to n=len and the cell in the row can be accessed like newTasks[n], progressTasks[n], etc. but since you have different lengths in the arrays the element at index n can be undefined for the smaller arrays so you have to check for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small snippet in JS on how you could do it. This is just an example of how the logic could look like. Of course, you have to modify it to make it work for React.

But you get the idea:

```js
const tasks = [{
    name: 'task1',
    status: 'new'
  },
  {
    name: 'task2',
    status: 'progress'
  },
  {
    name: 'task3',
    status: 'completed'
  },
  {
    name: 'task4',
    status: 'progress'
  },
  {
    name: 'task5',
    status: 'new'
  }
];

const newTasks = [];
const inProgressTasks = [];
const completedTasks = [];

for (let task of tasks)  {
  switch (task.status) {
    case "new":
      newTasks.push(task);
      break;
    case "progress":
      inProgressTasks.push(task);
      break;
    case "completed":
      completedTasks.push(task);
      break;
  }
}

const numTableRows = Math.max(newTasks.length, inProgressTasks.length, completedTasks.length);

const rows = [];

for (let n = 0; n < numTableRows; n++) {
  cellNewTask = newTasks[n]?.name ?? '-';
  cellInProgressTask = inProgressTasks[n]?.name ?? '-';
  cellCompletedTask = completedTasks[n]?.name ?? '-';

  rows.push([cellNewTask, cellInProgressTask, cellCompletedTask]);
}

console.log(rows);

// Now you just need to loop over the rows with React and render the Table
```